# java equivalent panels in qt

Tags: qt, panel

I would like to know the Java panel equivalent in QT. I mean which class do we need to use in QT, i.e. `qframe` or `qwidget`. I need to add many panels to my QT mainwindow.

Answer (score 6):

`QFrame`, `QScrollArea`, etc. have properties that handle panel appearance and are suitable for component containers and form layout.

`QWidget` has no `frameShape()`, `frameShadow()`, or `lineWidth()`, but it has layout and size operation methods, so it can also be used as a panel if you do not need borders, scroll, docking or other additional behavior.